# Why hasOne and HasMany generate the same Sql query in Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, activerecord, eloquent

I have two [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) Models:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Phone');
    }

    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Phone');
    }
}

class Phone extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

If `User::first()->phone()->toSql()` and `User::first()->phone()->toSql()` generate the same raw [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) query:

```
select * from `phones` where `phones`.`user` = ? and `phones`.`user` is not null
```

What is the difference between `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships?

Comment: The difference isn't the query, but what is returned by the relation; a model or a collection of models. `hasOne()` simply returns the first result from the collection; `hasMany()` returns the whole collection.... it's like the difference between `get()` and `first()`

Comment: @MarkBaker Both of them returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance (if I use `\App\Models\User::first()->phone()->get();` and `\App\Models\User::first()->phones()->get()`).

Comment: @MarkBaker You are right, the `hasOne` returns the first phone in the result, so there is no way to ensure that there is one and only one result?

Comment: Code from [`hasOne()` returns the result from first()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php#L14); code from [`hasMany()` returns the result from `get()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php#L14)

Comment: @MarkBaker Excellent, your last comment should be the accepted answer.